# How to add spread in inner shadow in svg?

Tags: html, svg, svg-filters

I have svg rectangle, and I need to add an inset-shadow with spread, how it works in figma.[image]
[rectangle with inner-shadow with  spread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwCHr.png)

Currently, I make a rectangle with blur and x, y position, but I don't know how to add spread for my filter for svg

```
<defs>
          <filter
            id={`inset-shadow`}
            x="-50%"
            y="-50%"
            width="200%"
            height="200%"
          >
            <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha">
              <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 0" />
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation={blur} />
            <feOffset
              dx={x}
              dy={y}
              result="offsetblur"
            />
            <feFlood flood-color={innerShadowColor} result="color" />
            <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in" />
            <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" />
            <feMerge>
              <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
              <feMergeNode />
            </feMerge>
          </filter>
<defs>

 <rect
        x={0}
        y={0}
        width={100}
        height={100}
        fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
        stroke={'red'}
        strokeWidth={10}
        pointerEvents="none"
        rx={10}
        filter={`url(#inset-shadow)`}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the spread by adding a feComponentTransfer to the alpha

```
<feComponentTransfer>
  <feFuncA type="linear" slope="1.5"/>
</feComponentTransfer>
```

I wrote this tool to help people understand how to write filters that duplicate graphic tools shadow

https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/xxPOoX

Answer (score -1):

Just need add

```
<feMorphology operator="dilate" radius={innerShadow.spread} />
```

```html
<svg>
    <defs>
              <filter
                id={`inset-shadow`}
                x="-50%"
                y="-50%"
                width="200%"
                height="200%"
              >
                <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha">
                  <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 0" />
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation={0} />
                            <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius={10} />

                <feOffset
                  dx={0}
                  dy={0}
                  result="offsetblur"
                />
                
                <feFlood flood-color={'red'} result="color" />
                <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in" />
                <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" />
                <feMerge>
                  <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
                  <feMergeNode />
                </feMerge>
              </filter>
    <defs>

     <rect
            x={0}
            y={0}
            width={100}
            height={100}
            fill="blue"
            pointerEvents="none"
            rx={10}
            filter={`url(#inset-shadow)`}
          />
</svg>
```